# How does one verify the derivative of $ f(x) = \sum^{K_2}_{k_2=1} c_{k_2} \exp\left(- \big(a^{(2)} - t^{(2)}_{k_2}\big)^2\right)$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I wanted to verify the derivative of the following equation:

$$ f(x) = \sum^{K_2}_{k_2=1} c_{k_2} \exp\left(- \big(a^{(2)} - t^{(2)}_{k_2}\big)^2\right)$$

for that I wanted to write a symbolic equation/representation of it so that I could manipulate it but I wasn't sure how to do that in mathematica. Ideally I'd like to get the following functionality:

$$ \frac{df(x)}{dt^{(2)}_{k_2}} = c_{k_2} \left(- \exp\big(z^{(2)}_{k_2}\big)\cdot2\big(a^{(2)}_{k_2} - t^{(2)}\big)\right)(-1)$$

so that it gave me the actual equation back symbolically (if that happens to be the correct one).

Ideally I'd like to extend it to accept vector inputs to as in:

$$ f(x) = \sum^{K_2}_{k_2=1} c_{k_2} \exp\left(- \big\| a^{(2)} - t^{(2)}_{k_2}\big\|^2\right)$$

but one thing at a time.

---

This is what I have tried so far. So before I try to me the upper limit of the sum symbolic, I am going to try to try it out a fixed $K_2$.

```
f[a_, t_, c_] = Sum[c[k2] * exp[a, t[k2]], {k2, 1, 3}]
```

which outputs:

[image]

which seems exactly correct. However, when I actually try to evaluate it and give it a vector it doesn't work as I expect:

[image]

instead of indexing at every location it just inserts the list for the variable, which isn't exactly what I had in mind. I was expecting something like:

$$ f = c_1 e^{-(a - t_1)^2} + c_2 e^{-(a - t_2)^2} + c_1 e^{-(a - t_1)^2} $$

$$ f = 5 e^{-(a - 1)^2} + 6 e^{-(a - 2)^2} + 7 e^{-(a - 3)^2} $$

---

I also tried a simple example with K2 fixed and it didn't quite work:

[image]

why does it return zero :/

Comment: @Jens I'll post that in a bit. patience. :)

Comment: Writing your code in *Mathematica* format as a replacement for or in addition to the traditional format makes it easier for the community to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you would like to differentiate the expression

```
f = Sum[c[k] Exp[-(a - t[k])^2], {k, kmax}]
```

with respect to `t[n]`, where `n` is an integer between `1` and `kmax`, to obtain

```
(* 2 E^-(a - t[n])^2 c[n] (a - t[n]) *)
```

Almost certainly, a similar question has been raised before, but I cannot find it now.  In any case, the obvious D[f, t[n]] with n a given integer, returns `0`.  For instance,

```
Assuming [kmax > 3, D[f, t[3]]]
(* 0 *)
```

And,

```
D[f, t[k]]
(* Sum[(2*c[k]*(a - t[k]))/E^(a - t[k])^2, {k, kmax}] *)
```

in effect treats all `t[k]` as the same variable.  An inelegant and, from my perspective, unsatisfying approach does, however, produce the desired output.

```
D[f[[1]] /. k -> n, t[n]]    
(* 2 E^-(a - t[n])^2 c[n] (a - t[n]) *)
```

Of course, this works only because any given `t[n]` occurs only in one term of the `Sum`.

Comment: sorry if this a newbie question, but what does `D[f[[1]] /. k -> n, t[n]] ` do? In particular, what does `D[f[[1]]` do? there were no parameters given to your definition of `f`, so how does it know what 1 and all the square brackets mean?

Comment: @Pinocchio  Please do not apologize for asking questions.  No one knows everything, and we all learn by asking.  `f[[1]]` extracts the summand, `c[k] Exp[-(a - t[k])^2]`, from `f`.  Try it.  ` /. k -> n` then replaces the index `k` by a particular value `n`.  (Actually, there is no need to do this replacement, but I did so for consistency with the explanation in the early part of the answer.)  Finally, `D[..., t[n]]` does the actual differentiation.

Answer (score 2):

In M11.2, the direct approach now works:

```
f = Sum[c[k] Exp[-(a-t[k])^2], {k, kmax}];

Assuming[i ∈ Integers && 1<=i<=kmax, Simplify @ D[f, t[i]]]
```

> 2 E^-(a - t[i])^2 c[i] (a - t[i])